# How to query number based SQL Sets with Ranges in SQL

Tags: sql-server, range, sql-like

What I'm looking for is a way in MSSQL to create a complex IN or LIKE clause that contains a SET of values, some of which will be ranges.

Sort of like this, there are some single numbers, but also some ranges of numbers.

EX:  SELECT * FROM table WHERE field **LIKE/IN '1-10, 13, 24, 51-60'**

I need to find a way to do this WITHOUT having to specify every number in the ranges separately AND without having to say "field LIKE blah OR field BETWEEN blah AND blah OR field LIKE blah.
This is just a simple example but the real query will have many groups and large ranges in it so all the OR's will not work.

Comment: So you want to invent new T-SQL syntax then?

Comment: What you're asking is not possible. The closest thing that comes into my mind is to create a 1-column temporary table containing all your values (with expanded ranges, not things like '1-10') and join it on `table.field`.

Comment: You could create a UDF that encapsulates all that logic so that when you needed to re-use it, it would be easy.

Comment: @Tab you mean hard-code the individual range values into a UDF? I suspect the sets are not the same every time.

Comment: No, the UDF would take a string containing the sets ('1-10, 13, 24, 51-60').   It would parse the string and create the logic, probably in the form of a table variable to join against.  I'm not volunteering to write it, mind you.   : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly easy way to do this would be to load a temp table with your values/ranges:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ranges (ValA int, ValB int)

INSERT INTO #Ranges
VALUES
 (1, 10)
,(13, NULL)
,(24, NULL)
,(51,60)

SELECT *
FROM Table t
JOIN #Ranges R
ON (t.Field = R.ValA AND R.ValB IS NULL)
   OR (t.Field BETWEEN R.ValA and R.ValB AND R.ValB IS NOT NULL)
```

The `BETWEEN` won't scale that well, though, so you may want to consider expanding this to include all values and eliminating ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CTEs.

First, create a numbers/tally table if you don't already have one (it might be better to make it permanent instead of temporary if you are going to use it a lot):

```
;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT
        1 as Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Numbers.Value + 1
    FROM
        Numbers
)
SELECT TOP 1000
    Value
INTO ##Numbers
FROM
    Numbers
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Then you can use a CTE to parse the comma delimited string and join the ranges with the numbers table to get the "NewValue" column which contains the whole list of numbers you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @TestData varchar(50) = '1-10,13,24,51-60'

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        1 AS RowCounter,
        1 AS StartPosition,
        CHARINDEX(',',@TestData) AS EndPosition

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CTE.RowCounter + 1,
        EndPosition + 1,
        CHARINDEX(',',@TestData, CTE.EndPosition+1)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE
        CTE.EndPosition > 0
)

SELECT
    u.Value,
    u.StartValue,
    u.EndValue,
    n.Value as NewValue
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Value,
        SUBSTRING(Value,1,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',Value) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('-',Value)-1 ELSE LEN(Value) END) AS StartValue,
        SUBSTRING(Value,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',Value) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('-',Value)+1 ELSE 1 END,LEN(Value)- CHARINDEX('-',Value))  AS EndValue
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            SUBSTRING(@TestData, StartPosition, CASE WHEN EndPosition > 0 THEN EndPosition-StartPosition ELSE LEN(@TestData)-StartPosition+1 END) AS Value
        FROM 
            CTE
        )t
    )u INNER JOIN ##Numbers n ON n.Value BETWEEN u.StartValue AND u.EndValue
```

All you would need to do once you have that is query the results using an IN statement, so something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Value IN (SELECT NewValue FROM (/*subquery from above*/)t)
```

Comment: Note that recursive CTEs do not scale well at all - I would test this with ranges much larger than you intend to support, just in case.